# Unable to understand format of test data while evaluating training model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, linear-regression

I am training a regression model that takes approximates the weights for the equation :
**Y = R+B+G**
For this, I provide pre-determined values of R, B and G and Y, as training data.

```
    R    = np.array([-4, -10,  -2,  8, 5, 22,  3],  dtype=float)
    B    = np.array([4, -10,  0,  0, 15, 5,  1],  dtype=float)
    G    = np.array([0, 10,  5,  8, 1, 2,  38],  dtype=float)

    Y    = np.array([0, -10, 3, 16, 21, 29, 42],  dtype=float)
```

The training batch consisted of 1x3 array corresponding to Ith value of R, B and G.

```
    RBG = np.array([R,B,G]).transpose()
    print(RBG)

    [[ -4.   4.   0.]
    [-10. -10.  10.]
    [ -2.   0.   5.]
    [  8.   0.   8.]
    [  5.  15.   1.]
    [ 22.   5.   2.]
    [  3.   1.  38.]]
```

I used a neural network with 3 inputs, 1 dense layer (hidden layer) with 2 neurons and the output layer (output) with a single neuron.

```
    hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_shape=[3])
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
```

Further, I trained the model

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([hidden, output])
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))
    history = model.fit(RBG,Y, epochs=500, verbose=False)
    print("Finished training the model")
```

The loss vs epoch plot was as normal, decreasing and then flat.

But when I tested the model, using random values of R, B and G as

```
    print(model.predict([[1],[1],[1]]))
```

expecting the output to be 1+1+1 = 3, but got the Value Error:

```
    ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_2_input to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Any idea where I might be getting wrong?

Surprisingly, the only input it responds to, is the training data itself. i.e,

```
    print(model.predict(RBG))

    [[ 2.1606684e-07]
    [-3.0000000e+01]
    [-3.2782555e-07]
    [ 2.4000002e+01]
    [ 4.4999996e+01]
    [ 2.9000000e+01]
    [ 4.2000000e+01]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, the problem is in your shape of the input. You need to transpose `[[1],[1],[1]]` this input then you will have the shape that is expected by the model.

so `npq = np.array([[1],[1],[1]]).transpose()` and now feed this to `model.predict(npq)`

Comment: It worked like magic! But can you tell me the reason behind this. I have been going through these weird errors once I started using NumPy.

Comment: Every model has layers and each layer expects input in certain shape or dimension. These errors are common when playing with arrays or tensors. So before feeding any input always make sure the shape, dimensions etc of input matches to what is being expected by the input receiver. An easy way is to just print them beforehand.

Comment: But the np.array([[1],[1],[1]])  does give the dimensions (3, ) as asked in the error. I don't see the reason behind transposing it.

Comment: this (3,) means number of rows are three meaning 3 samples with only values of 'R', but it requires each sample to have 3 columns where all columns represents R,G,B values respectively. If you calculate the shape of RGB you printed above you'll get (7,3) i.e. 7 samples each with RGB values (3 columns) and now when you  wanna predict one sample your final input shape must be (1,3).

Comment: I tried that too.... np.array([1,1,1]) But this doesn't work either. (Sorry if I am being too inquisitive but I need to get this done well)

Comment: yes bc np.array([1,1,1]) has shape (3,) and it requires (1,3).

Comment: what you are seeing in the error is without the sample size given in it like (3,) or (1,), bc it does not know how many samples you are giving but does know what should be the size of each one of them. So for your understanding, you can transform these (3,) and (1,) to (1,3) and (1,1) where first 1s are sample sizes means how many samples are there.